# Why is my grid not saving more than one row?

Tags: acumatica

I have a grid embedded in a popup that stores user selected items from another grid. The user highlights the desired row, clicks a button, and it is added as a new row in the grid based on the information of the highlighted row. For some reason, it is not adding a new row, but instead it is overwriting the current one:

Adding new row for the first time:
[image]

Trying to add second row:
[image]

The first image I selected to add a new row the first time. The second image shows that when I add a second row, it overwrites the current row instead of inserting a new row. I tried to do this whole process at first with a PXFilter and found that PXFilters only allow for one row to be stored. I then created a blank table of the same name as the filter with all of the fields, changed the view to PXSelect, and thought it might be that, but it didn't fix it.

The code for the Add to MTO button is:

```
    public PXAction<PMProject> addToMTO;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Add to MTO")]
    [PXButton]
    protected virtual void AddToMTO()
    {
        SOSiteStatusSelected row = sitestatus.Current;
        if (row == null)
            return;

        bool isMade = false;

        //NOTE: If you have a more efficient method to check if a view contains a row, please include that in the answer.
        foreach (MTOLSelected testLine in SelectedItems.Select())
        {
            if (testLine.ItemID == row.InventoryID)
            {
                isMade = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isMade)
        {
            MTOLSelected line = new MTOLSelected();
            SelectedItems.Insert(line);

            line.ItemID = row.InventoryID;
            line.ItemCD = row.InventoryCD;
            line.Price = row.CuryUnitPrice;
            line.Descr = row.Descr;

            SelectedItems.Update(line);
        }
        else
        {
            SelectedItems.Ask("This item is already moved into the MTO List", MessageButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

The DAC is:

```
[Serializable]
public class MTOLSelected : IBqlTable
{
    [PXDBIdentity]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "MTOLID")]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public abstract class id : IBqlField { }

    //Might more Drawing Number and Qty Required to this new table
    #region ItemID
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "ID")]
    public virtual int? ItemID { get; set; }
    public abstract class itemID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion  

    #region ItemCD
    [PXDBString(15)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Item CD")]
    public virtual string ItemCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class itemCD : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Descr
    [PXDBString(255)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Desc")]
    public virtual string Descr { get; set; }
    public abstract class descr : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Qty
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Qty")]
    public virtual int? Qty { get; set; }
    public abstract class qty : IBqlField { }
    #endregion  

    #region Price
    [PXDBDecimal()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Price")]
    public virtual decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public abstract class price : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Length
    [PXDBDecimal()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Length")]
    public virtual decimal? Length { get; set; }
    public abstract class length : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Feet
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Feet")]
    public virtual int? Feet { get; set; }
    public abstract class feet : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Inches
    [PXDBDecimal()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inches")]
    public virtual decimal? Inches { get; set; }
    public abstract class inches : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DAC appears to need IsKey on the Identity field:  [PXDBIdentity(IsKey=true)]

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple I forgot! That worked! Thanks!